# Dropping Spine.js into an existing app?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, spine.js

I've been looking at quite a few of the MVC for JavaScript frameworks lately and I quite like the overall feel of Spine.js as well as the fact it is using CoffeeScript.  That said, my primary concern at this stage is I need to be able to drop an MVC framework iteratively into a fairly large existing application.  Most of the documentation that I have seen on Spine.js focuses on creating new applications.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to go about doing this; if there is a good tutorial somewhere that would be great too, but Google was not my friend on that one.

Or is this just a bad idea and I should go elsewhere when dealing with legacy?  While Angular didn't click with me in the same way; it did however seem pretty straight forward on how I could use it iteratively with a legacy application.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's rather a bad idea to do it "iteratively". I'm working as freelancer for a company where they decided to do a complete UI rework splited over a few releases. In the first stage it was planned to drop the existing JS and use spine js as MVC and require js as AMD. So far so good - but the process was "iteratively". The project/App is quite complex and it took over a half year (I'm involved since 2,5 months).

It was a big mistake to leave all the existing JS and "iteratively" replace the functionality for the release. We ran into multiple problems, because of that. If you have hundreds of js files, inline scripts, dependencies it's much easier to simply throw them away, because you can tell literally if your new code works or not. Otherwise you always have to distinguish whose fault is it: new or old code.

This was also responsible for trouble that could have been avoided, or at least alleviated, if it were a hard cut:

- The product owner was not really aware of the status, because he couldn't see any visible progress. He only figured out bugs and misbehaviour. That was unsatisfying/frustrating for both parties. One quote I've heard over and over again: "It did work the other day/before - now it's not"
- You start to update some outdated libs, plugins that sometimes will cause compatibility issues, because API's tend to change, so you have to fix that in your old code as well. Means: at some point it starts to feel like hacking around problems and not to develop a cool/good App. Thats's extremely frustrating too.
- It took waaays longer than expected/estimated.
- You've been developing in dependency of your old code that does not exist in the very end.

My personal advice is: don't do it iteratively. Do hot fixes for the live App and develop the new one on a separate branch.

Comment: I agree. Starting fresh is the way to go. In our experience spine apps, or frontend apps in general are quite speedy to develop, and starting fresh lets you build in test coverage from the beggining. If you are using Hem with spine we try to make this TDD stuff slick, but the documentation on that process could use some work.

Comment: I think this terrible advice. A large and mature code base should almost never be rewritten, rather it must be improved iteratively.  You speak of the product owner not being aware of the progress; if you throw out the entire product and start over the product owner is going to be well aware that you have taken a big step backwards for quite some time.  By prioritizing the customer's needs for improvements to the product and intermingling underlying code practices both going forward and retroactively as time permits we can improve the code base while also showing the customer progress.

Comment: Continuing on my reply above.  It seems a few people agree with me. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/dont-rewrite-your-application.html.  Also, notice above I said "almost never", there are certainly some cases where a total rewrite is necessary, but that is the outlier rather than the rule.  And it is most certainly not the case for the project I'm currently working on.

Comment: @bigtunacan "a mature application" - well I've rarely seen something like this in the real world. Most web apps/sites I've seen had no documentation, no tests, no coding standards, coded with a just-get-it-done-as-fast-as-possible approach by many people just hacking it that way. I absolutely agree, that If you have quality code, then you can improve and refine it iteratively - but IMHO the average/common web app/site isn't anything you can attribute with quality. However: In my case and with the existing code it was a mistake to do it iteratively.

Comment: There is always room for improve, but in our case we adhere to many agile best practices; pair programming, unit testing, code reviews etc... I would say in the 16 years I've been working as a professional developer this is one of the best code bases I've had the privilege of working on and I don't have any desire for a rewrite in the particular instance :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how conforming any legacy app that didn't have an explicit mvc structure into a spine.js or backbone or angular etc. is likely to be a drop in experience.

Iteratively converting is going to be a lot like writing a new app minus the boilerplate stuff for defining the app GUI interaction. Start by focusing on models and controllers by pulling out components that fit well into the MVC structure. I would suggest early on to avoid certain app interaction components of Spine like stacks, and routes as those make a lot more sense once everything else is ready to be used according to spine convention.